# Windows dir is giving .. & . in output in some directories, but not others. How to always exclude parent directories?

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to get a count of directories in a folder, which means I want to exclude the `..` & `.` listings typically given by Windows when you say `dir`.

The command I've been using until now is `dir  "E:\My Folder" /A:d-r | findstr Dir(s)` which works fine and goes straight to the total folder count.  However on a different drive (so same command, just O:\My Folder) the `..` are still included resulting in a +2 count.  Both drives are NTFS.

Why could this be happening and how to always ensure `..` is excluded?

```
06/30/2021  05:01 PM    <DIR>          .
06/30/2021  05:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
```

Comment: Take a look at `dir`'s /b` switch (*b*are format, without header, summary and `.`, `..`): `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:d-r "E:\My Folder"^|find /c /v ""') do @echo %%a`

Comment: `FOR /D %%G IN ("E:\My Folder\*") DO set /a fcount+=1`

Comment: @Squashman: counts all folders - regardless of the ReadOnly flag.